# How can I get each frame in camera2 api in android studio like PreviewCallback in camera api and ImageAnalysis.Analyzer in camerax?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

How can I get each frame in Camera2 api in android studio like PreviewCallback in Camera api and ImageAnalysis.Analyzer in Camerax? I looked at other questions but they do not answer my question properly.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, use [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/ImageReader).  Configure it for YUV_420_888, and get its Surface to use as part of Camera session configuration.

Then include its Surface in each CaptureRequest you send to the camera, and process new frames in `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()`.

Comment: Could you please show me some example in code?

Comment: You can see the basics of using an ImageReader for JPEG still captures in the Camera2Basic (https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) sample from Google.  To use it each frame, use YUV_420_888 instead, and include the ImageReader Surface in the repeating request for preview, instead of just the still capture request.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

```
val surface: Surface = imageReader.surface
val captureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(
CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW
).apply {
addTarget(surface)
addTarget(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.holder.surface)
}
// This will keep sending the capture request as frequently as possible 
until the session is torn down or session.stopRepeating() is called

session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest.build(), null, cameraHandler)
imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
val image = reader.acquireLatestImage()
Log.d(TAG, "Image available in queue: ${image.timestamp}")
image.close()
}, imageReaderHandler)
```